# How to find the value of variables from a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be real numbers s.t. they are not equal to zero. Let
>   $$
> P = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & 0\end{array}\right)
> $$
>   Be a matrix. If $P^{-1}=P$ ; then $\alpha=?$, $\beta \gamma=?$

As far I got ahead is that

$$
P^{T} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\alpha & \gamma \\ \beta & 0\end{array}\right)
$$

$$
P^{-1}=\frac{1}{-\beta\gamma} P^T
$$

Hence  $\beta\gamma=-1$

What's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second identity is not quite right, what you want is the [transpose of the cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix)

$$
P^{-1} = \frac{1}{-\gamma \beta}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -\beta \\ -\gamma & \alpha \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1/\gamma \\ 1/\beta & -\alpha/\beta\gamma \end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: Oh! That was the mistake. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that$$P^{-1}\neq\det(P)P^T.$$

Note that $P^{-1}=P\iff P^2=\operatorname{Id}_2$